# Builder error while uploading Next.js project to Heroku

Tags: heroku, sass, deployment, next.js

I am having a problem with deploying the next.js app to Heroku. Builder says:

```
remote: postcss-resolve-url: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
remote: https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
remote: Failed to compile.
remote:
remote: ./pages/index.js
remote: Module not found: Can't resolve '../styles/Constructionpage.module.scss' in '/tmp/build_642a3d7a/pages'
remote:
```

This is my **/pages/index.js** file imports:

```
import style from "../styles/Constructionpage.module.scss";
import Head from "next/head";
```

The structure looks like this:

```
pages
  -index.js
styles
  -Constructionpage.module.scss
```

But locally everything works without any errors/warnings.
Does anyone have an idea why this happens? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you're running your site with `yarn dev`, you're using your local server to render your site **as you navigate to each page**. When you build, Next generates **every page on your site**. Your error is likely coming from a page you didn't access in dev.

Remember that Next is set up for [server side rendering static assets](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation), so it will ingest whatever data (and CSS) you give it and give you back a [performance-optimized set of pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization) that get rehydrated client-side.

`PostCSS` is [natively set up to work with Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-postcss-config). Check their docs, you'd have to provide a lot more background to debug this if it's still giving you trouble.

Comment: If I understood correctly, it should crash when built, but when I run **npm run build** it builds fine. It crashes only on heroku. Also, is it possible that there were some conflicts on heroku repository? I am asking because currently on heroku there is an other version of build, where same scss file has other name

Comment: Yeah could be different deps at Heroku

Answer (score 0):

I've just changed the name of file to the initial one. It was **"constructionpage.module.scss"**, then I changed it to **"Construstionpage.module.scss"** and it started giving errors. I changed it back to **"constructionpage.module.scss"** and it worked. I don't know why actually :) All imports were correct

Comment: Can you tell what the previous' file name was?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).